# Pulling items for presentation in python - I have a list taken from outlook, but need to break those items into individual strings

Tags: python

I am creating a Jarvis style screen and have pulled data from outlook for upcoming meetings that I wish to present on the screen.

The function pulls data from outlook and presents it in a list: -

```
event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 12, 30), Subject='meeting 1 description', 
Duration=60)
    event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 14, 0), Subject='meeting 2 description', Duration=60)
    event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 8, 30), Subject='meeting 3 description', Duration=60)
    event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 15), Subject='meeting 4 description', Duration=45)
    event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 11, 0), Subject='meeting 5 description ', 
    Duration=90)"
```

This is great, but what I want to do now is have this present as:

```
Start time = 'start time'
```

Subject = 'Meeting description'
Duration = 'duration of meeting'

Is there a way of slicing up the string in a list item and then pulling that into the code as I want it presented? Basically splitting the item in a list into component parts?

Here is the code that pulls the lists: -

```
def get_date(datestr):
    try:  # py3
        adate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datestr.Start.timestamp())
    except Exception:
        adate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datestr.Start))
    return adate

    def getCalendarEntries(days=3, dateformat="%d/%m/%Y"):

    Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    appointments = ns.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items
    appointments.Sort("[Start]")
    appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    begin = today.date().strftime(dateformat)
    tomorrow = datetime.timedelta(days=days) + today
    end = tomorrow.date().strftime(dateformat)
    appointments = appointments.Restrict(
    "[Start] >= '" + begin + "' AND [END] <= '" + end + "'")
    events = []
    for a in appointments:
        adate = get_date(a)
        events.append(event(adate, a.Subject, a.Duration))
    return events


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    events = getCalendarEntries()"""
```

Thanks all,

Graeme

Comment: Let me get this right, you want from this ```event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 12, 30), Subject='meeting 1 description', 
Duration=60)``` get something like this ```{"Start": "Mon, 30 Nov 2020 12:30:00", "Subject": "meeting 1 description", "Duration": "60"}```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe a bit hacky but the syntax for `event` in your string is the same as one would define a dictionary. So we can replace 'event' with 'dict' and call `eval` which basically evaluates a string as if it was Python code. so for example if you run this

```
import datetime
event_str = r"event(Start=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 12, 30), Subject='meeting 1 description', Duration=60)"
dict_str = event_str.replace('event','dict')
my_dict = eval(dict_str)
print(my_dict)
```

this will print

```
{'Start': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 12, 30), 'Subject': 'meeting 1 description', 'Duration': 60}
```

So my_dict will be a dictionary that you can pull various bits out of, such as `my_dict['Start']` will give you the start (as datetime), etc

you would need to call this construct on each element of your `events` list, eg the following should create a list of dictionaries, one for each event

```
all_dicts = [eval(e.replace('event','dict')) for e in events]
```

of course you can save yourself all this trouble if you created dictionaries in the first place, so replace the relevant line in your loop with

```
events.append(dict(Start=adate, Subject=a.Subject, Duration=a.Duration))
```

and then use `dict` functionatility to get the fields via `events[i]['Start']` etc

Comment: Great thank you - I'll give that a go.  That makes life easier as I was struggling with lists - makes much more sense.  Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with after your suggestion - worked like a treat - thank you so much :) You are a super star!

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
from collections import namedtuple


event = namedtuple("event", "Start Subject Duration")


def get_date(datestr):
    try:  # py3
        adate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datestr.Start.timestamp())
    except Exception:
        adate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datestr.Start))
    return adate


def getCalendarEntries(days=3, dateformat="%d/%m/%Y"):
    Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    appointments = ns.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items
    appointments.Sort("[Start]")
    appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    begin = today.date().strftime(dateformat)
    tomorrow = datetime.timedelta(days=days) + today
    end = tomorrow.date().strftime(dateformat)
    appointments = appointments.Restrict(
        "[Start] >= '" + begin + "' AND [END] <= '" + end + "'")
    events = []
    for a in appointments:
        adate = get_date(a)
        events.append(dict(Start=adate, Subject=a.Subject, Duration=a.Duration))
    return events


if __name__ == "__main__":
    events = getCalendarEntries()

print ("Time:", events[1]['Start'])
print ("Subject:",events[1]['Subject'])
print ("Duration:",events[1]['Duration'])
```

Comment: great! feel free to consider accepting the answer per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Note also lists in python are 0-based so the first element of `events` is `events[0]` not `events[1]`. I saw it in your code and thought I would mention it in case you did not know

Comment: yes - just spotted that as I was missing my appointment for tomorrow :)  I'll accept the answer now.  First time for me using this site :)

Comment: done - thanks again for your help - most useful and saved me hours of Googling :)